# What is the criteria for the other donut option to become viable in Don't get fired?

Tags: dont-get-fired

Occasionally the "You found a box of donuts" event occurs in Don't get fired, which will always lead to you getting fired if you choose to open the box instead of doing nothing.

Is there a stage of the game that opening the box will result in a positive outcome?
If yes, at what stage is this and what is the criteria that needs to be met before you should open the box?

Answer (score 3):

No. This option disappears after becoming vice president.